# Change A to Z to Smallest to Largest in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Have numbers in Excel 2016 column that sorts with *A* to *Z* when it should be *smallest* to *largest* or vise versa. How do I change from *A* to *Z* to *smallest* to *largest*?

Comment: Could you put an example?

Comment: sounds like your cells/columns are defined as a text type rather than a numeric type. If you need leading zeros etc, you do this by setting a display format.

Comment: The numbers are all numeric and are written like 1/8 as well as 1:4 in two different columns and don't give me the ability to sort from smallest to largest.

Comment: `1:4` is not a number it is a text/string.

Comment: `A to Z` means ascending, i.e. smallest to largest, regardless of numerical or string data

Comment: Alright, is there a way to be able to manipulate it? Or a way to rework it to mean the same?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc except when you have 1/4 and 1/46 and it claims 1:46 is smaller than 1/6.

Comment: of course, in string `"1/4" < "1/46" < "1/6"`, what's wrong with that? If you want to sort numbers then you must calculate the value as numbers. There's no fraction type in Excel so 1/4 would be string, otherwise you need `=1/4` to get the value

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you! Will add '+' to each and will make a percentage. Different but still works. Thanks again!